# JavaFx - Removing Node Stored in Array

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, event-handling

I have an array of buttons declared as a class variable that is added to a gridPane. When I try to remove the buttons of the array from the gridPane the event handler is being recognized but the node is not being removed.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < Cols; j++) {
            bArray = new Button[Rows][Cols];

            bArray[i][j] = new Button();
            bArray[i][j].setMinSize(20,20);
            bArray[i][j].setMaxSize(25,25);

            gridBoard.setVgap(1); //vertical gap in pixels
            gridBoard.add(bArray[i][j], j, i);

            bArray[i][j].setOnMouseClicked(e->checkNeighbors());
       }
}
```

// Local Method

```
public static void checkNeighbors() {
        // This print out statement is met, but the removal does not occur
        System.out.println("Action is called");
        gridBoard.getChildren().remove(bArray[0][1]);
        gridBoard.getChildren().remove(bArray[0][2]);
        gridBoard.getChildren().remove(bArray[0][3]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding `bArray` in each iteration and the only valid references that are left at the end of the for loops are from `[Rows][0]` to `[Rows][Cols]`.

As an example if `Rows = 4` and `Cols = 4`, that would be that at the end the only valid references are `[3][0]`, `[3][1]`, `[3][2]` and `[3][3]`, and you are trying to remove `[0][1]`, `[0][2]`, `[0][3]`.

You should move the initialization of `bArray` before the loops start.

```
    bArray = new Button[rows][cols];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

         bArray[i][j] = new Button();

         // ......
       }
```

Comment: Oh yeah now I see, thanks for catching that and sharing!